# SSLHandShakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake making GET Request

Tags: java, spring, http, ssl

Here is the code that I'm using

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
        .newInstance()
        .host(HOST)
        .scheme("https")
        .path("/query");

builder.queryParam("function", "TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY");
builder.queryParam("symbol", exchange.isEmpty() ? ticker : (exchange + ":" + ticker));
builder.queryParam("interval", "30min");
builder.queryParam("apikey", System.getenv("LEO_ALPHA_VANTAGE_KEY_12"));

try {
  URL uri = new URL(builder.build().toUriString());
  System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
```

Which causes this exception, this is with the debug=all turned on and I have tls1.2 on as well

```
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 237
[Raw write]: length = 242
0000: 16 03 03 00 ED 01 00 00   E9 03 03 5A 8B 6B 97 B1  ...........Z.k..
0010: 9D 19 5F 18 2A F5 32 F0   32 FE 29 64 31 0B A2 8C  .._.*.2.2.)d1...
0020: A6 57 80 79 AE F7 7F D3   12 40 02 00 00 64 C0 24  .W.y.....@...d.$
0030: C0 28 00 3D C0 26 C0 2A   00 6B 00 6A C0 0A C0 14  .(.=.&.*.k.j....
0040: 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F 00 39   00 38 C0 23 C0 27 00 3C  .5.....9.8.#.'.<
0050: C0 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40   C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04  .%.).g.@...../..
0060: C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2C   C0 2B C0 30 00 9D C0 2E  ...3.2.,.+.0....
0070: C0 32 00 9F 00 A3 C0 2F   00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00 9E  .2...../...-.1..
0080: 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A   C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13  ................
0090: 00 FF 01 00 00 5C 00 0A   00 16 00 14 00 17 00 18  .....\..........
00A0: 00 19 00 09 00 0A 00 0B   00 0C 00 0D 00 0E 00 16  ................
00B0: 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D   00 1C 00 1A 06 03 06 01  ................
00C0: 05 03 05 01 04 03 04 01   04 02 03 03 03 01 03 02  ................
00D0: 02 03 02 01 02 02 00 17   00 00 00 00 00 14 00 12  ................
00E0: 00 00 0F 61 6C 70 68 61   76 61 6E 74 61 67 65 2E  ...alphavantage.
00F0: 63 6F                                              co
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
main, called closeSocket()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at com.compass.leo.util.AlphaVantage.getStockTimeSeries(AlphaVantage.java:128)
        at com.compass.leo.util.AlphaVantage.getStockTimeSeries(AlphaVantage.java:84)
        at com.compass.leo.LeoApplication.main(LeoApplication.java:42)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1002)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at 

com.compass.leo.util.AlphaVantage.getStockTimeSeries(AlphaVantage.java:116)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
        ... 12 more
```

I'm wondering what the error would be here? I'm able to easily make the call to this site through postman,

A GET request to: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=TSX:CPG&interval=30min&apikey=demo

What could be the issue here?

Comment: The peer probably doesn't speak TLSv1.2.

Comment: @EJP this is how the entire stacktrace error looks like if I put TLS1.2 in http.protocols, vs if I just put TLS1.1

TLS1.2: https://gist.github.com/MaazAli/8ad14a29b52fce9d4e55459d135b389e

TLS1,TLS1.1: https://gist.github.com/MaazAli/2498025d5d46168ad841881b08f76d19

In either case, it fails.

Comment: For me `www.alphavantage.co` works (@EJP: using 1.2 and with a GCM-SHA2 suite that only exists in 1.2) but `alphavantage.co` fails -- and from the trace your code is apparently using the latter. Use the hostname that works.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 seems to do the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Once I had a similar problem that took me 2 days to figure out. I don't know if that is going to be your case, but it might worth a shot.

I was running the application on a server that had a proxy blocking the request. When I send the https://my-server/my-service request it would return an HTTP page from the company saying "Content blocked from IT". This HTTP page couldn't complete the handshake since it wasn't an HTTPS page.

The solution was to ask IT to whitelist the domain on the server.